# svg sprite load with webpack and react

Tags: reactjs, networking, svg, webpack, sprite

Hi I am using svg sprite I created using icons8 website for all my website icons, and the icons are working but it seems that the website loads them more than once per page (if i open the network tab i can see it loaded twice or more). I have been looking for a solution for a while now and I cant seem to find the cause of this.

I work with react so I have a component for Icon which uses the  tag with xlinkHref attribute.

did anyone encounter such behavior? if yes what would be the best way to approach a solution?